# Baking textures on headless machine (batch baking)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, baking

Is it possible to bake textures from the command line?

This is useful for setting up batch jobs, baking an entire level for example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the bake operator can run in background mode, for both Blender-Internal and Cycles Baking.

A very simple script could look like this:

### Bake Once

`bake.py`:

```
 import bpy

 # Like pressing the 'Bake' button in Blender
 # this will remain locked until the bake is complete.
 bpy.ops.object.bake(type='COMBINED')

 # You might want to inspect the materials and extract images
 # but for this example, simply select by name
 image = bpy.data.images["Untitled"]

 # save-as by setting the target path and saving
 image.file_format = 'PNG'
 image.filepath_raw = "//my_new_bake.png"
 image.save()
```

Execute the bake with:

```
 blender --background bake_test.blend --python bake.py
```

For batch jobs you would have to change the selection before calling `bpy.ops.object.bake` each time.

---

### Bake Everything

This next example is more comprehensive, and uses the `is_dirty` image flag to detect which images to save, giving each image a `_bake` suffix.

`bake_all.py`:

```
# Blender v2.8x +
import bpy
import os

scene = bpy.context.scene
for obj in scene.objects:
    obj.select_set(False)

for obj in scene.objects:
    if obj.type != 'MESH':
        continue

    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    obj.select_set(True)

    bpy.ops.object.bake(type='COMBINED')
    obj.select_set(False)

# save all baked images
for image in bpy.data.images:
    if image.is_dirty:
        # foo.png -> foo_bake.png
        filepath, filepath_ext = os.path.splitext(image.filepath_raw)
        image.filepath_raw = filepath + "_bake" + filepath_ext
        image.save()
```

Execute the bake with:

```
 blender --background bake_test.blend --python bake_all.py
```

---

Further ideas for batch baking which might be useful.

- Automate baking an entire game-level:

  loop over each group and bake its objects *(or each group matching a naming convention, ending with `.bake` for example)*
- Automate baking existing models:

  A utility script which loads in models from an external format (OBJ, FBX, 3DS... etc), unwrap, assign images, bake and exports.
- Automate low-poly mesh creation with the decimate modifier, and bake normal maps (high->low poly meshes).
- Bake textures over time (create a baked image sequence).
- Create a utility which runs back in a background process so you can keep on using Blender.

Comment: I think need to register this, I got errors:     bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
RuntimeError: unregister_class(...):, missing bl_rna attribute from 'RNAMeta' instance (may not be registered)

Blender quit

C:\3D>C:\blender-3.4.0-alpha+master.d4d40f3b69d8-windows.amd64-release\blender.exe --version
Blender 3.4.0 Alpha
        build date: 2022-10-03

Comment: I tested with blend file and need active image ...Info: No active image found in material "Procedual..." (0) for object "Sphere" Info: No active image found in material "Procedual ..." (0) for object "Cylinder"