# How to Bake Texture Sequence in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I would like to use EEVEE's Shader to RGB and Cycles's Fisheye Lnes Camera together.

To emulate Shader to RGB in Cycles, I want to render texture sequence of diffuse passes that respond to the lighting being animated in Cycles.

However, the bake function seems to handle only one frame.
Is there a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can try the add-on I wrote for [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33469/baking-textures-as-image-sequence-by-script-in-cycles/48078#comment173417_48078), recently updated for 2.8x: [blender-image-bakery.py](https://gist.github.com/p2or/43194fcab3f42bab9b70ff1cc2b7637a)

Comment: @p2or
Thanks! I tested the add-on. It did a great job of animation baking, but it could only bake one object at a time. There are many objects and materials in my scene. It feels inefficient to join them as one object for baking. The blender's built-in bake feature supports multiple objects. Is there any way to process to bake animations and multiple objects at the same time?