# Is it possible to bake animated shadows?

Tags: animation, lighting, baking, shadowcatcher

I use the add on Grove to animate trees in the wind and project the shadow on a wall. But the method is not very efficient because the scene is already very full and the trees require a lot of processing power. I would like to animate the trees in another file and bake the shadows there. Then I want to import them and put them on the wall. Is this possible with animated shadows? How do I proceed?

Comment: There are several answers here that might solve your problem.  - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-to-make-a-model-cast-shadows-onto-the-world-texture-background/72354#72354

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this add-on **[Sequence Bakery](https://gist.github.com/p2or/43194fcab3f42bab9b70ff1cc2b7637a)** from @p2or ... it seems to do what you are asking for ... tested on 2.93

[image]

I expect you know how to bake ... just be sure your newly created image is saved before you run operator. Sequence will be saved into that directory as well.

Baked Image sequence of shadow pass (without indirect and other passes :)
Previewed in Solid view mode ...

[image]

Originally posted [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48078/2214) ... just the link to addon of current version is "hidden" in comments.