# Change 'Image Sequence' images, visualize in Image Editor, save after changes

Tags: image, image-sequence

I add a plane in Blender. Then in Shader mode I create Image Texture Node and set 'Image Sequence'. This displays the texture to the plane which can be changed by keyboard <- and ->. Also, I can visualize the image texture in Image Editor. This everything works fine. If I do some changes in Paint mode, it appears in both.

The problem is when I want to have colorful texture and add ColorRamp. In object mode, it looks good. Everything is colorful. But in Image Editor, the image is still grayscale. Do you have any idea how to achieve the colorful image also in Image Editor? Also I want to save newly changed images, but not sure how.

[image]

Please do you have any advices? Thank you very much. Sorry, I am beginner.

Comment: Hello ! What you're looking for is texture baking, but you can't do it real-time I'm afraid. The flow of information here is top right editor (input map) > bottom right (pixel shader) > left (viewport shading). And it can't flow the other way around

Answer (score 0):

Interesting ... For a single image Blender warns you about unsaved images (and automatically is set to save them) ... but that is not happening for image sequence, hmm ...

You would have to save them manually under *Image Editor > Properties > Image > Save* ... each individually (in case we are speaking about manually painted images).

[image]

About saving as coloured ... as suggested by Gorgious ... use **Bake** (switch to *Cycles*, plug *ColorRamp* directly to *Output* node and switch *Bake Type* to **Emit**

[image]

For baking sequence check [this addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/250463/2214). Ad a new *Image Texture* node with new *Image*, *Save* image and with node still selected (*Active*) press *Animated Bake*.
Even written for 2.8, worked for me under 3.5 ...

[image]