# Blender 2.8+ - Baking textures on headless machine (batch baking)?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, baking

I'm a noob when it comes to scripting so I came across this solution: [Baking textures on headless machine (batch baking)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10860/baking-textures-on-headless-machine-batch-baking) But unfortunately, I can't make it work for 2.8+:

**`bake_all.py`**

```
import bpy
import os

scene = bpy.context.scene
for obj in scene.objects:
    obj.select = False

for obj in scene.objects:
    if obj.type != 'MESH':
        continue

    scene.objects.active = obj
    obj.select = True

    bpy.ops.object.bake(type='COMBINED')
    obj.select = False

# save all baked images
for image in bpy.data.images:
    if image.is_dirty:
        # foo.png -> foo_bake.png
        filepath, filepath_ext = os.path.splitext(image.filepath_raw)
        image.filepath_raw = filepath + "_bake" + filepath_ext
        image.save()
```

**Q:** How to execute the script in latest versions?

---

Updated the code based on the comments and it still doesn't work:

```
import bpy
import os

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'


for obj in scene.objects:
    obj.select_set(False)

for obj in scene.objects:
    if obj.type != 'MESH':
        continue

    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    obj.select_set(True)

    bpy.ops.object.bake(type='COMBINED')
    obj.select_set(False)

# save all baked images
for image in bpy.data.images:
    if image.is_dirty:
        # foo.png -> foo_bake.png
        filepath, filepath_ext = os.path.splitext(image.filepath_raw)
        image.filepath_raw = filepath + "_bake" + filepath_ext
        image.save()

bpy.ops.image.save
```

This is not working on my remote PC, it works fine on my local PC but not on my remote farm. What am I doing wrong?

this is not doing anything

```
# save all baked images
for image in bpy.data.images:
    if image.is_dirty:
        # foo.png -> foo_bake.png
        filepath, filepath_ext = os.path.splitext(image.filepath_raw)
        image.filepath_raw = filepath + "_bake" + filepath_ext
        image.save()
```

in terminal it says

> Info: Baking map saved to internal image, save it externally or pack
> it

only the bake file is created that is not usable... do I need to add the filepath?

I tried to add save file and download blender file to open it locally but no baked textures within...

[image]

Comment: I get `line 6, in <module>
    obj.select = False
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'select'`

Comment: Okay, my bad it did have some outdated lines. Please check the answer you provided, I updated the code for 2.8+. basically `obj.select` became a method `obj.select_set(state)` and now with view layers you have to set the active object per view layer. `scene.objects.active = obj` becomes `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj`

Comment: Does the update solve your issue? @sephiroth85

Comment: no, i updated it but still getting this

Comment: line 15, in <module>
    bpy.ops.object.bake(type='COMBINED')

Comment: line 201, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: No valid selected objects

Comment: Do you actually have a mesh object in your file ?

Comment: @Gorgious after bake it seems that blender doesnt save the files?

Comment: Have tested the script and it seems to work properly. I'd suggest share your blend preferably using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add the blend to your question to figure out your issue...

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=KR7z6QQR" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/KR7z6QQR/)

Comment: done, what I want to do it, is to run baking on my remote render farm that I have

Comment: anything? @brockmann

Comment: as mentioned this is not working on my remote PC, it works fine on my local pc but not on my remote farm